# didSelectRowAtIndexPath with more than one actions

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my app, when the user taps on a row, a detail `ViewController` is shown to display more information about the object, like a master/detail `application`.

Now, I have included a second action to the method,to put the row in edit mode to allow the user to reorder the rows.

I needed to put this second action at this method because I don't want to use the default edit button to enter the edit mode.

As you may guess, when the user taps on a row, the detail `ViewController` is first shown and then, after closing it, the selected row shows the reorder control and the delete button.

Here is my code for the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    [tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    ToDoItem *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.detailViewController.editToDoItem = object;
}
```

What should I do inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to launch the two actions, one at a time, what kind of condition could I use to launch one action or the other?

Comment: What you are asking sounds impossible. How can you show editing mode in _this_ view controller and also go to a _different_ detail controller. Nobody can be in two places at once. You cannot use the same gesture to mean two contradictory things. This is exactly why there is a standard response to tap (go to the detail controller) and a standard edit button (put the table in edit mode).

Comment: Why dont you have a longpressgesture to switch to edit mode. I believe after going to detail screen and then the selected row to edit mode doesn't make sense in user point of view.

Comment: @matt, thank you for your comment, but this is not impossible. There apps on the app store that use this behaviour, like the app any.do, when the user taps on row the detail View is shown, when the user taps on it for a second+-, the row can be move to another position.

Comment: But that sounds like two different gestures, single tap vs double tap. I said the _same_ gesture could not do two different things.

Comment: @matt, please take a look at my own answer to the question, may be you  think it is a good solution to the issue, and thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, the best solution is to remove the line of code:

```
[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

from the `didSelecRowAtIndexPath` method and to include it at the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.